# Is there a free Visual Studio extension that "drops markers" like CodeRush

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The paid version of CodeRush has a feature where you can "drop a marker" in the code and later go back to them.  They work like a stack, so you can drop markers (across multiple files) and go back to them in the reverse order that you dropped them.

Is there a dev studio extension that does anything similar?

Comment: Visual Studio supports Bookmarks.  Use Edit + Bookmarks to see the shortcut keys.  It isn't great, but free with your paid license fee or the free Express edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want, you can work around this limitation (No "Drop Marker" feature in CodeRush XPress). Here's how you can do it:

1. Create a new DXCore plug-in via the File -> New -> Project... -> Visual C# -> DXCore -> Standard Plug-in item. Enter name if necessary and click OK.
2. On the next "DXCore Project Settings" accept the defaults (click OK).
3. Drop an Action component (DXCore section) from the Toolbox on the PlugIn1 design surface.
4. Select the Action component and fill the "ActionName" property, e.g. "MyDropMarker".
5. Create an event handler for the "Execute" event of this Action component.
6. Inside this handler type this code line: "CodeRush.Markers.DropSelection();" (no quotes)
7. Build the plug-in project.

You're almost done...

1. Start a new instance of Visual Studio IDE.
2. Press the CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+O to open the Options Dialog.
3. In the tree view on the left, navigate to this folder: "IDE"
4. Select the "Shortcuts" options page.
5. Click on the "New Keyboard Shortcut" button.
6. Press the key you would like to bind to the MyDropMarker action, e.g. ALT+Home
7. Select the "MyDropMarker" action in the Command combo box.
8. Modify the context of the shortcut if necessary (e.g. Focus\Documents\Code Editor (so it has a green tick))
9. Save the options - click OK.

Now you have your own feature similar to the CodeRush's "Drop Marker" feature.

Answer (score 0):

There's a completely free version of CodeRush called "[CodeRush Xpress](http://www.devexpress.com/crx)" - it also has markers support.

Comment: It does not, however, allow you to drop your own markers.  It does allow you to collection markers dropped by other actions.